# How to display database value into specific index of html table?

Tags: php, html, ajax, select, html-table

I need help for display selecting data value from database into a specific position in a html table.
I have made the code for displaying it but it will display the data in index 0 on the html table.

Anyone know how to make the data will displaying at index 1 on the html table?
I've try to change the index but it failed to displaying it.
Here my code:

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "../php/bkk/bkk_isel.php",
            success: function(data){
  var list = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    $('#mat').val((list[i]['material']));
    $('#lok').val((list[i]['lokasi']));
    $('#kpl').val((list[i]['kapal']));
    $('#po_numb').val((list[i]['po']));
    var tr = "<tr>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['tanggal']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['no_pol']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['netto']+"</td>";

    tr += "</tr>";

    $("#table_s tbody").append(tr);
  }
  return false;
}
});
});
```

This is the {data} that i use. i use php function for the data

```html
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","silo");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


// Data for Titik1
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM temp2");
$rows = array();

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

[image: Like this Image]

Comment: what value is receive in the variable 'data'. Could you post a sample of that too

Comment: i've edit my code. i give my code for retrieve the {data}

Answer (score 0):

can you please more explain what shape you mold with html Table. basically table row always append with general indexing. if you need a black row before your data row so kindly append a blank row in your html table.

Comment: from my code i made. the data that displaying going into index 0 of the table right?
i want to make it started in index 1 of my table. do you know how?

Comment: Add a Empty Row in a table , Than Data Row adding at 1 Index

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index number of the row to show on the html table, then you need to add a new column before all other columns. This new column will show the serial number of the row. For example before this line:

```
tr += "<td>"+list[i]["tanggal"]+"</td>";
```

Add this line:

```
tr += "<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td>";
```